# Eliminating Duplicate records based on priority table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, join

I have 2 tables, 1 (Product) is having below data

```
orderName       Skey
3.0             100
Pen             100
Scale           101
Pen             101
Bottle          102
```

Priority table 2nd one has below data

```
orderName       Priority
Scale           1
Pen             2
Bottle          3
3.0             4
```

I want to remove duplicate values(skey) from product table based on order priority present in Priority table.

The output is should give is

```
orderName   Skey
Pen         100
Scale       101
Bottle      102
```

I am not sure how can I do this using single query.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full working example:

```
DECLARE @Products TABLE
(
    [orderName] VARCHAR(24)
   ,[Skey] INT
);

DECLARE @priority TABLE
(
    [orderName] VARCHAR(25)
   ,[Priority] TINYINT
);

INSERT INTO @Products ([orderName], [Skey])
VALUES ('3.0', 100)
      ,('Pen', 100)
      ,('Scale', 101)
      ,('Pen', 101)
      ,('Bottle', 102);

INSERT INTO @priority ([orderName], [Priority])
VALUES ('Scale', 1)
      ,('Pen', 2)
      ,('Bottle', 3)
      ,('3.0', 4);


SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES P.[orderName], P.[Skey]
FROM @Products P
INNER JOIN @priority PR
    ON P.[orderName] = PR.[orderName]
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P.[Skey] ORDER BY PR.[Priority]);
```

[image]

Comment: OP needs "remove duplciate values", not select.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH cte AS (SELECT Product.*, 
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Skey 
                                       ORDER BY (SELECT Priority
                                                 FROM priority
                                                 WHERE Product.orderName = priority.orderName)) rn
              FROM Product)
DELETE
FROM cte
WHERE rn > 1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=88c7adb83caa70562e6049ba4e65d588)

PS. `orderName` column in `priority` table MUST be defined as unique. `Priority` column also needs uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

use "Partition by key1 Order By key2" to order data with partition. then choose first item from each partition. Here comes the code

```
create table Product(orderName varchar(100),Skey int);
insert into Product values('3.0',100);
insert into Product values('Pen',100);
insert into Product values('Scale',101);
insert into Product values('Pen',101);
insert into Product values('Bottle',102);

create table Priority(orderName  varchar(100),Priority int);
insert into Priority values('Scale',1);
insert into Priority values('Pen',2);
insert into Priority values('Bottle',3);
insert into Priority values('3.0',4);

select orderName,skey FROM
(
    select p.orderName,skey,pr.Priority,row_number() over(partition by skey order by pr.Priority) as rowNum 
    from Product p join Priority pr on p.orderName=pr.orderName 
) t where t.rowNum = 1
```